# How to update a select box based on the values of another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Rails app I have a form with two select boxes (one of them being a *multiple* select box):

```
<label>Project owners</label>
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Huey</option>
  <option value="2">Dewey</option>
  <option value="3">Louie</option>
</select>

<label>Invoice recipients</label>
<select>
  <option value="1">Huey</option>
  <option value="2">Dewey</option>
  <option value="3">Louie</option>
</select>
```

How can I limit the `invoice recipients` to the `project owners` that have been selected?

For example, if *Dewey* and *Louie* get selected as `project owners`, the `invoice recipients` select box should only contain *Dewey* and *Louie* as well.

I know this is possible through jQuery but my jQuery skills are very limited.

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
<label>Project owners</label>
<select id="owners" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Huey</option>
  <option value="2">Dewey</option>
  <option value="3">Louie</option>
</select>

<label>Invoice recipients</label>
<select id="recipients">
  <option value="1">Huey</option>
  <option value="2">Dewey</option>
  <option value="3">Louie</option>
</select>
```

then

```
$('#owners').change(function(){
    $('#recipients').empty().append($(this).find('option:selected').clone())
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jEWUd/)

Comment: That works. Thank you! Please excuse my silly question but what would I have to do if I wanted this `clone` function to run on page load already and not only after it got clicked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependent select jquery plugin for this purpose:

http://simpleweb.github.io/jquery-dependent-selects/